# В чём смысл и преимущества #!/usr/bin/env?

Tags: linux, bash, unix, shell

Этак с начала времён (юниксовых, т.е. 1.01.1970) в начале скрипта рекомендовалось использовать shebang / hashbang - строку, указывающую на используемый интерпретатор, например:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo 'hello world'

#!/usr/bin/python
print 'hello world'

#!/usr/bin/python3
print('hello world')
```

Недавно наткнулся на рекомендацию использовать вместо этого такую форму:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
echo 'hello world'

#!/usr/bin/env python
print 'hello world'

#!/usr/bin/env python3
print('hello world')
```

Пожалуйста, объясните, как это работает и в чём преимущества такого подхода? Если есть ограничения и/или недостатки по сравнению с обычным способом - то и о них хотелось бы услышать.

Comment: Кросс-линк на StackExchange: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/29608/why-is-it-better-to-use-usr-bin-env-name-instead-of-path-to-name-as-my

Comment: Простейший пример из практики: в Linux bash лежит в `/bin/bash`, а во FreeBSD в `/usr/local/bin/bash` и первый вариант не запустится. В своё время напоролся на это и теперь везде использую только второй вариант)

Comment: Правда, меня иногда беспокоит, а вдруг `/usr/bin/env` когда-нибудь кто-нибудь тоже переместит...

Comment: ассоциация: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2429511/

Comment: ассоциация: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10376206/

Comment: сделай симлинк, и точно найдет, будет 100% переносимость, ну... если только не при первичной загрузке

Comment: > во FreeBSD в /usr/local/bin/bash
@andreymal а как так баш оказался в локал? Я думал эта папка чисто для тех кто устанавливает через make install. Вероятность что кто-то скомпилил себе баш туда нулевая. Поэтому я реально не понимаю заморочки с env

Comment: @SergeyPonomarev не знаю, спросите у создателей FreeBSD

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Основная идея - улучшение переносимости. Не гарантируется, что на различных системах исполняемый файл будет лежать по пути, который указан в shebang.

Использование `env` позволяет снизить этот риск за счет запуска команды на основе данных из переменной среды `PATH`

Более того, если по каким-либо причинам вместо стандартного исполняемого файла пользователь хочет использовать свой, то ему достаточно добавить путь к этому файлу в `PATH` без необходимости исправления скриптов:

```
~ $ cp /bin/bash /home/soon/python                                         
~ $ export PATH=/home/soon:$PATH                                                 
~ $ env python                                                                   
[soon@archlinux ~]$ exit
```

В примере выше я скопировал `bash` к себе в домашнюю директорию (переименовав при этом файл в python), добавил путь в `PATH` и запустил *python* с помощью `env`, которая усужливо запустила `bash`, т.к. нашла его раньше.

Еще одним примером является использование виртуальных окружений при разработке на Python (virtualenv). Поскольку они также перебивают `PATH`, `env` позволяет использовать нужную версию исполняемого файла:

```
~ $ workon black-box-challenge-2016-py2     
~ (venv:black-box-challenge-2016-py2) $ env python

Python 2.7.11 (default, Mar 31 2016, 06:18:34) 
[GCC 5.3.0] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import sys
>>> print sys.executable
/home/soon/.virtualenvs/black-box-challenge-2016-py2/bin/python
>>>
```

Comment: Отличный пример про venv. А `workon` - это что-то новое для меня.

Comment: Я уже не помню, где `workon` взял, вроде как отсюда: http://virtualenvwrapper.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html

Answer (score 17):

краткое резюме из информации, приведённой в ответах к этому вопросу и к аналогичным вопросам:

- [Why is it better to use “#!/usr/bin/env NAME” instead of “#!/path/to/NAME” as my shebang?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/29608/110559)
- [Why is #!/usr/bin/env bash superior to #!/bin/bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21612980/4827341)

### преимущества:

- будет запущена программа не из конкретно указанного файла, а из того, что встретится первым в списке каталогов, заданных переменной окружения `PATH` пользователя, запустившего скрипт.

  полезно для случаев, когда по указанному пути в системе, на которой будет выполняться скрипт, такого файла нет, или когда пользователь модифицирует эту переменную окружения для того, чтобы выполнялась какая-то особая программа (другая реализация, другая версия).

### недостатки:

- будет запущена программа не из конкретно указанного файла, а из того, что встретится первым в списке каталогов, заданных переменной окружения `PATH` пользователя, запустившего скрипт.

  например, разные пользователи (или тот же пользователь, но с модифицированным содержимым этой переменной окружения) могут получить разные результаты выполнения одного и того же скрипта.
- программы `/usr/bin/env` может не существовать в системе, где будет запускаться скрипт, соответственно, попытка запуска будет неудачной.
- нельзя будет указать дополнительной опции для выполняемой программы. так получится:

  ```
  #!/путь/к/программе опция
  ```

  а так — нет:

  ```
  #!/usr/bin/env программа опция
  ```

Comment: У вас ошибка, в месте, где говорится, что нельзя указать параметры при использовании `env`. Можно. Вот параметры запуска: `env [OPTION]... [-] [NAME=VALUE]... [COMMAND [ARG]...]` http://linux.die.net/man/1/env

Comment: @zed, вы отчасти правы (по поводу программы *env*), но у *shebang-а* есть свои ограничения: [The optional‑arg should either not be included or it should be a string that is meant to be a single argument (for reasons of portability, it should not contain any whitespace)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)#Syntax)

Answer (score 11):

Это связано с переносимостью скриптов. Дело в том, что путь к `python`, к примеру, на разных системах может отличаться, а вот путь к `env` на всех системах неизменный. Поэтому, вызывая `env` и передавая ей в качестве аргумента нужный интерпретатор, можно быть уверенным, что скрипт будет запущен вне зависимости от того, где на самом деле находится интерпретатор (главное, чтобы он был в `PATH`).

Answer (score 5):

Команда `env` отображает текущие переменые окружения. А если стоит с командой

```
env bash
```

то выполняет команду с текущеми перемеными окружения.

В некоторых системах при запуске интерпритаторов используется не текущие переменые окружения , а считываются из файлов или даже ставятся по умолчанию. И если Вы изменили или добавили переменые окружения , то они не будут учтены в запускаемом скрипте, а при запуске через `env` все переменые будут учтены.

Comment: Ошибся, не здесь это применял.

Answer (score 2):

Начиная с версии coreutils **8.30 от 2018-07-01** `env` поддерживает опцию `-S`, которая разбивает следующую за ней строку на отдельные параметры, таким образом стало возможным передать интерпретатору несколько дополнительных опций, а так же поменять переменные окружения. Примерно так:

```
#!/usr/bin/env -S переменная1=значение переменная2=значение python3 -дополнительные -опции
```