# Почему буквы алфавита с "р" по "ю" не входят в диапазон "а-я"?

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения, кодировка, python-2.x, unicode

**Поясню сразу**: я знаю, что python 2 требует явного объявления строк как юникодовых. Понимаю, что это и не должно работать корректно. Мне интересна "анатомия" поломки. Что именно внутри `re.compile()` и `regex.search()` производит такой результат?

---

Судя по нижеприведённому коду, диапазон `'а-яё'` не включает в себя диапазон `'р-ю'`, зато диапазон `'р-ю'` включает `'ё'`.

*mcve.py:*

```
# coding=utf-8

import re

# Это панграмма, она содержит все буквы алфавита
test = 'широкая электрификация южных губерний даст мощный толчок подъёму сельского хозяйства'

regex1 = re.compile('[а-яА-ЯёЁ\s]+')
regex2 = re.compile('[а-яА-ЯёЁшьрэтфцюыхущчъ\s]+')
regex3 = re.compile('[а-яёшьрэтфцюыхущчъс\s]+')
regex4 = re.compile('[а-яр-ю\s]+')

print regex1.search(test).group()
print regex2.search(test).group()
print regex3.search(test).group()
print regex4.search(test).group()
```

Результат:

> �
>   широкая электрификация южных губерний даст мощный толчок подъёму сельского хозяйства
>   широкая электрификация южных губерний даст мощный толчок подъёму сельского хозяйства
>   широкая электрификация южных губерний даст мощный толчок подъёму сельского хозяйства

Я убедился, что все буквы алфавита от "А" до "Я" и от "а" до "я" [идут в Юникоде подряд](http://unicode-table.com/en/#cyrillic), кроме "Ёё", которые явным образом добавлены в регулярное выражение.

Постепенно добавляя буквы, на которых прерывается поиск по первому выражению, я пришёл к диапазону `а-яА-ЯёЁшьрэтфцюыхущчъ`. Если отсортировать добавленные буквы, получается почти сплошной интервал: `"ртуфхцчшщъыьэю"`.

Если убрать заглавные буквы, т.е. `"[А-ЯЁ]"`, то неожиданным образом поиск прерывается на "с". Интервал становится сплошным: с "р" и до "ю". Это `regex3`.

И наконец оказывается, что теперь интервал можно свернуть и даже убрать "ё" (`regex4`).

Что вообще происходит?

```
 python --version
Python 2.7.6
```

---

Если явным образом сделать юникодовую строку и регулярное выражение, то всё работает как должно. Но ведь как-то работает и без этого. Объясните, как?

```
test2 = u'широкая электрификация южных губерний даст мощный толчок подъёму сельского хозяйства'
regex5 = re.compile(u'[а-яА-ЯёЁ\s]+')
```

Comment: А почему у регулярок не указан Юникод?

Comment: @Visman наверное потому, что и так работало. :)) Проверил с юникодом - работает как должно. Но ведь и без этого как-то работает. Хочу понять этот феномен, что происходит и почему.

Comment: Вообще регуляркам обычно пишут не юникод строки, а raw строки, то есть наверно должно быть re.compile(r'[а-яА-ЯёЁ\s]+')

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Самый простой способ посмотреть, что же не так с регуляркой - поставить `debug` флаг. Причем в таком случае абсолютно нет нужды лезть в потроха - они покажут то же самое. В этом можно убедиться, если залезть руками в `%python_folder%/Lib/sre_parse.py` и добавить там пару `print`-ов на строку 438 - выглядит она как-то тактак:

```
elif this == "[":
            # character set
            set = []
            setappend = set.append
##          if sourcematch(":"):
##              pass # handle character classes
            if sourcematch("^"):
                setappend((NEGATE, None))
            # check remaining characters
            start = set[:]
            while 1:
                this = sourceget()
                if len(this) == 1:
                    # Вот ровно в этом месте парсер перебирает содержимое [] 
                    print(source.tell(), "ORD: ", ord(this))
                if this == "]" and set != start:
                    break
```

Так вот этот `print` покажет все абсолютно то же самое, что и debug - то что буковки на самом деле не буковки.

```
regex1 = re.compile('[а-яА-ЯёЁ\s]+', re.DEBUG)

max_repeat 1 2147483647
  in
    literal 208
    range (176, 209)
    literal 143
    literal 208
    range (144, 208)
    literal 175
    literal 209
    literal 145
    literal 208
    literal 129
    category category_space
```

Сразу видно, что что-то совсем нечисто, потому что первым должен быть `range(ord('a')-ord('я')`, а вместо него чепуха какая-то. А все от того, что строки в кодировке UTF8 (указана явно в файле), а тип у них - байты. Они могут отображаться нормально в терминале, если кодировки совпадают. Я пользуюсь Pycharm и его консоль в UTF8. Но если бы я запустил то же самое на стандартном терминале винды, то отобразилась бы натурально каша (типа такой - ╨Я╤А╨╕╨▓╨╡╤В), ибо кодировка CP866.

Например,

```
print("Привет")
# НО!
for char in "Привет":
    print(ord(char), repr(char))
```

В debug выводе число 208 - это первая половинка UTF8 символа 'а' - 176 - вторая половинка, затем следует дефис и снова первая половинка символа 'я' - в этом можно убедиться, открыв исходник в любом HEX редакторе. В итоге неверный интервал. 
Соответственно, когда парсер перебирает содержимое квадратных скобок он натыкается не на буквы, а на байты, а точнее на половинки букв в кодировке UTF8. Можно симулировать поведение регулярки таким кодом:

```
reg_min = 144
reg_max = 209

result = []
for char in test:
    ordedr = ord(char)
    if ordedr >= reg_min and ordedr <= reg_max:
        result.append(char)
    else:
        break
print(ord(regex1.search(test).group()))
print(list(map(ord, result)))

>>> 209
>>> [209]
```

Comment: Хороший анализ. Может стоит немного разжевать в ответе, что `literal 208` это первый байт `а` из первого диапазона в `[а-яА-ЯёЁ]`, а `range (176-209)` трансляция диапазона от второго байта `а` до первого байта `я` (а то ведь не все смогут сразу разобраться)

Comment: @avp я вроде бы сразу понял, но можно и разжевать)

Comment: @NickVolynkin, интересно, а в питоне можно самому вызвать `setlocale()` (из libc)? Если да, то можно было бы самому указать  UTF-8 и посмотреть, что получится.

Comment: @avp, можно, конечно же: `import locale locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, ('RU','UTF8'))` Но локаль изменяет шрифты (набор символов?), формат даты, часовой пояс и т.д., но однобайтовые строки от этого не станут интерпретироваться как двухбайтовые.

Comment: Не совсем. Зависит от библиотеки (я не знаю, что использует питон). У меня в `Ubuntu 16.04 LTS` libc-ные `regcomp()/regexec()` для паттерна `[а-я]` по разному себя ведут при разных locale -- `C` (это по умолчанию, если `setlocale()` не вызывать) и `en_US.UTF-8` (это у меня environment LANG, т.е. вызываем `setlocale(LC_ALL, "")`). / Ну, можете сами поиграться.

Answer (score 7):

Нативная поддержка Unicode в Python - только с третьей версии.
Используйте ее. Обратите еще внимание на первые две строчки исправленного файла

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import re

# Это панграмма, она содержит все буквы алфавита
test = 'широкая электрификация южных губерний даст мощный толчок подъёму сельского хозяйства'

regex1 = re.compile('[а-яА-ЯёЁ\s]+')
regex2 = re.compile('[а-яА-ЯёЁшьрэтфцюыхущчъ\s]+')
regex3 = re.compile('[а-яёшьрэтфцюыхущчъс\s]+')
regex4 = re.compile('[а-яр-ю\s]+')


print(regex1.search(test).group())
print(regex2.search(test).group())
print(regex3.search(test).group())
print(regex4.search(test).group())
```

Вывод:

```
gaal@linux-t420:~/WORK/test> ./1.py
широкая электрификация южных губерний даст мощный толчок подъёму сельского хозяйства
широкая электрификация южных губерний даст мощный толчок подъёму сельского хозяйства
широкая электрификация южных губерний даст мощный толчок подъёму сельского хозяйства
широкая электрификация южных губерний даст мощный толчок подъ
```

Comment: Да, я знаю об этом, и если явно указать `u'строка'`, то всё хорошо. Но что происходит в этом примере? Как компилируются регулярные выражения из таких строк?

Comment: Ну, видимо, потому что python 2 работает в текущей кодовой странице. Что есть целевая платформа для Вашего скрипта - Windows, Linux какой версии?

Comment: Linux Ubuntu 14.04. Кстати, а `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-` по производимому эффекту чем-то отличается от просто `# coding: utf-8`?

Comment: По этим двум строчкам - разницы нет, можете писать как Вам больше нравится.

Comment: Просто вы обратили внимание на измененные первые строки, вот я и заподозрил, что различия есть.

Comment: Я Питон 3 запускал ;) хороший тон - добавлять первой строчке название и путь к интерпретатору, чтобы система автоматически могла определить какой Питон вызывать.

Comment: Ваш ответ верный в смысле "проблемы XY". Действительно, не стоит ждать корректных результатов от некорректного использования. Но я хотел бы экскурсию во внутренности Питона с объяснением причин такой поломки. Такой вот вивисекторский интерес. :) А что касается hashbang - знаю, но привычки всегда ставить ещё нет. Кстати, попиарю вопрос в тему: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/541589/181472

Comment: Да-да-да, плюсанул тот вопрос. Реально актуален.
Касательно вивисекторства. Что можно сделать.
Первое - распечатать таблицы символов.
Второе - посмотреть кишки regex модуля в Python2. И сделать соответствующие выводы.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/42266/discussion-between-nick-volynkin-and-gecube).